# JavaFX - drag a row from a tableview into a textarea

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, tableview

Consider a tableview inside a JavaFX application. The tableview contains data about people:

```
id    firstname    lastname

1     John         Doe
```

Each of the rows of the tableview can be used to instantiate a Person object:

`new Person(Integer id, String firstname, String lastname)`.

Here is what I want to do:

I want to select one of the Persons inside the tableview and drag it with my mouse into a textarea. Inside the textarea I want to print the String:

`1    John    Doe`.

I know that I have to implement three functions to achieve this: `onDragDetected(), onDragOver() and onDragDropped()`.

I was thinking to start with:

```
public void onDragDetected(DragEvent dragevent) {
    Person person = tvPersonData.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}
```

This works. But I have to somehow get my Person into the DragBoard object (`dragevent.getDragboard()`). I think that I do. And then maybe my other functions can use whatever is inside my dragboard.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use a custom object in a `DragAndDrop` gesture, you need to define a custom `DataFormat` for the object:

```
DataFormat personDataFormat = new DataFormat("com.package.Person");
```

You obviously need to replace the `com.package.Person` will the full path to the class you are creating this for.

Note also that in order for a class to be used as a `DataFormat`, that class must be `Serializable`. This is accomplished by implementing the `Serializable` interface in your `Person` object:

```
class Person implements Serializable {}
```

*Another thing to remember is that JavaFX properties are not `Serializable` so if you use `StringProperty` in your `Person` object, this will not work; you'll need to create a wrapper class that holds the data you need.*

---

Once you have your `DataFormat` and `Person` implementing `Serializable`, you can copy your `Person` object to the Clipboard just like any other content; you just need to specify the `DataFormat` for it:

```
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.put(personDataFormat, tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
```

Dropping onto the `TextArea` is going to be similar. You'll define the `DataFormat` and then add the code to process as desired:

```
Person droppedPerson = (Person) db.getContent(personDataFormat);
textArea.appendText(droppedPerson.getName() + "\n");
```

---

**Full example application below:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DragObject extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
    private final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Create a basic layout
        // **********************************************************************************************
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Configure a regular TableView
        // **********************************************************************************************
        configureTableView();

        tableView.setItems(sampleData());
        tableView.setPrefHeight(200);
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        root.getChildren().add(textArea);

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // This method will configure our drag-and-drop functionality
        // **********************************************************************************************
        initDragAndDrop();

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Set the Scene for the stage
        // **********************************************************************************************
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Configure the Stage
        // **********************************************************************************************
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Application");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void configureTableView() {

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Just a standard sample TableView
        // **********************************************************************************************

        TableColumn<Person, String> colName = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> colEmail = new TableColumn<>("Email");

        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colName, colEmail);

    }

    private void initDragAndDrop() {

        DataFormat personDataFormat = new DataFormat("Person");

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Add drag and drop to the TableView
        // **********************************************************************************************
        tableView.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            // **********************************************************************************************
            // Drag was detected, allow any type of transfer
            // **********************************************************************************************
            Dragboard db = tableView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            // **********************************************************************************************
            // Add the selected Person to the clipboard, using our custom DataFormat
            // **********************************************************************************************
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.put(personDataFormat, tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            db.setContent(content);
        });

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Add drag and drop to the TextArea
        // **********************************************************************************************
        textArea.setOnDragOver(event -> {

            // **********************************************************************************************
            // Person was dragged over the TextArea; accept it only if dragged from a node other than itself.
            // In this case, this condition isn't necessary, but still good practice
            // **********************************************************************************************
            if (event.getGestureSource() != textArea
                && event.getDragboard().hasContent(personDataFormat)) {

                // **********************************************************************************************
                // For this example, we'll allow ANY transfer type again
                // **********************************************************************************************
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);

            }

            // **********************************************************************************************
            // Consume the event. We'll handle placing content into the TextArea next
            // **********************************************************************************************
            event.consume();
        });

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Add handler to the TextArea to accept a Person object that's been dropped and add the person's
        // name to the TextArea
        // **********************************************************************************************
        textArea.setOnDragDropped(event -> {

            // **********************************************************************************************
            // First, ensure the object being dropped was a Person object
            // **********************************************************************************************
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasContent(personDataFormat)) {

                // **********************************************************************************************
                // Get a reference to the Person being dropped. Note that you need to 
                // cast the object to a Person so Java knows what object type you're 
                // working with.
                // **********************************************************************************************
                Person droppedPerson = (Person) db.getContent(personDataFormat);
                textArea.appendText(droppedPerson.getName() + "\n");

                success = true;
            }

            // **********************************************************************************************
            // Complete the event
            // **********************************************************************************************
            event.setDropCompleted(success);

            event.consume();
        });

    }

    private ObservableList<Person> sampleData() {
        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Just some sample Persons for our TableView
        // **********************************************************************************************
        return FXCollections.observableList(Arrays.asList(
                new Person("John Williams", "jwilliams@et.com"),
                new Person("Howard Shore", "hshore@shire.com"),
                new Person("Danny Elfman", "delfman@scissorpalace.org")));

    }
}
```

> **RESULT:**

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you SO much! I was starting to grow desperate over this drag and drop technique and you just explained it perfectly! Plus, I did not find any information about defining a custom dataformat at all. Thx again, you just made me very happy  :-)